# Measurability of $\mathbb{R}^n$-Random Field

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-functions

Let $(X_x)_{x\in [0,1]^d}$ be a collection of integrable random variable defined on a (common) probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.  Under what condition is the map:
$$
[0,1]^d\ni x \mapsto X_x \in L^1(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{P})
$$
measurable (or even continuous).

I'm looking for "reasonable" conditions (i.e.: not $X_x$ is constant as a function of $x$); preferably with citations.

Comment: This question seems a little bit too general, at least for me. What about applying Fubini linke theorems, i.e. given a measurable function $f : [0,1]^d \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ with suitable assumptions, of course boundedness suffices? Then $X_x = f(x,.)$.